How to properly use autosized columns and auto-flow in CSS grid?
I have relatively simple markup of up to five elements. Three of the elements are mandatory and always exist, rest are optional.
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1 mandatory"></div>
  <div class="item-2 optional"></div>
  <div class="item-3 optional"></div>
  <div class="item-4 mandatory"></div>
  <div class="item-5 mandatory"></div>
</div>

I need items 2, 3 and 4 to always be 100% of the container and each occupy it's own row. Item 1 and Item 5 should share first row if they can both fit on it without overflowing. Otherwise Item 5 go down on it's own row.
Illustrated below:

Most success I had from the following setup:
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1 mandatory"></div>
  <div class="item-2 optional"></div>
  <div class="item-3 optional"></div>
  <div class="item-4 mandatory"></div>
  <div class="item-5 mandatory"></div>
</div>

/* color coding for illustration */
.item-1 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.item-2, .item-3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.item-4 {
  background: pink;
}

.item-5 {
  background: lightgreen;
}


.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, max-content));
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -2;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.item-2, .item-3, .item-4 {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.item-5 {
  width: min-content;
}

It works in generally moving Item 5 around in "ideal" conditions, but fails in two regards:

If Item 5 is smaller than 150px, there is a hole. Instead I need Item 1 to grow to fill all available space, and Item 5 to be of min-content width.
If Item 1 or Item 5 is too large, it overflows container instead of moving Item 5 on last row where everything would fit.


CSS grid won't help here

Any other possible way to achieve such layout?
